# Positioning a popup on secondary screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup, popupwindow

I'm trying to create a private web page for myself that would open a website as a popup window on my secondary monitor. I can position the popup automatically within my main monitor, where the browser covers the whole screen, just fine, but when I try to automatically move the created popup window to my other screen, it simply refuses to go there.

The code I was trying with is

```
window.open('https://tweetdeck.twitter.com','Tweetdeck','width=1664,height=488,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=-1680,top=591');
```

I also tried with `.moveTo` with same results.

The `top` positioning works correctly, but `left` doesn't seem to have effect when it is less than 0. `left=-1680,top=591` is the exact location I want to move it to (checked with autohotkey window spy), but Chrome doesn't seem to be willing to do that.

I have a feeling it might be due to [position error correction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Note_on_position_and_dimension_error_correction), but the window in that position is very much on my desktop and fully visible.

Is there a way I could automatically move the window to the specified pixel coordinates in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a challenging issue but I'm afraid it's impossible in `dual view` mode; I have also two monitors working on dual view mode. Check this out

```
if (!w || w.closed) {
    w = window.open("","links","menubar=0,scrollbars=0,width=600,height=480");
}
w.document.write("<p>X: " + w.screenX + "Y: " + w.screenY + "</p>");

// center in
w.moveTo((screen.width/2)-(640/2),(screen.height/2)-(480/2));
// horizontal positioning fails

// try the negative value
w.moveTo(-300,300); // it fails again

w.focus();
// it only works if you move the popup window by hand 
// after that it has already been instantiated
```

Maybe it could work if I merge my two screens, not sure. I'll check it in a meantime and post back the results here.

`EDIT` Yes, it works if I merge my two screens in so-called `horizontal span` mode.

I believe there's another solution like building a tiny C/C++ app to handle the active window but isn't that weird :)

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var commandtoRun = "C:\\PopupWinHandler.exe"; 
oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
```

However, here is the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/wewajapi/1/edit) experiment, so you can play around.